# Python/Pandas: Array (back) to DataFrame

Tags: arrays, pandas, dataframe, normalize

I applied following function to normalize the columns in my dataframe.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize

pd.DataFrame(normalize(traffic, norm='l2', axis=1, copy=True, return_norm=False))
```

However, this function returns an array

```
array([[ 0.19781966,  0.21981735,  0.        , ...,  0.05655909,
         0.        ,  0.00033033],
       [ 0.18050277,  0.2031944 ,  0.        , ...,  0.15848418,
         0.        ,  0.00032616],
       [ 0.14110768,  0.16995336,  0.        , ...,  0.0820779 ,
         0.        ,  0.00023619],
```

Is there any way to write the normalized data into the original "traffic" dataframe and replace the raw values?

I realized that when I apply

```
pd.DataFrame(normalize(traffic, norm='l2', axis=1, copy=True, return_norm=False))
```

all original column names and the index are gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `normalize` function returns an array of the same shape as the `traffic` DF you can do it this way:

```
pd.DataFrame(normalize(traffic, norm='l2', axis=1, copy=True, return_norm=False),
             columns=traffic.columns, index=traffic.index)
```

Comment: That seems to help. I only wonder why in each column, the values are not scaled from 0 to 1. In my case, they are ranging from 0.238 to 0.413?

Comment: @Rnaldinho, AFAIK they supposed to sum up to `1.0`

Comment: MinMax Scaling seems to work jsut fine. The values are each scaled from 0 to 1 in each column, though the MinMax is indeed very sensitive for outliers. Should normalization() not also scale from 0 to 1?

Comment: I think I solved it: `pd.DataFrame(normalize(wikipedia, norm='max', axis=0, copy=True, return_norm=False),
             columns=wikipedia.columns, index=wikipedia.index)`. Note norm='max', axis=0.